# puppet remote copy files from a host other than the puppet-server

Tags: ruby, puppet

Is there a way to copy files to one host (foo) from another (bar) in the same domain (mydom.org), where neither of them is the puppet-server, but both of them have *puppetd* running ? I am looking for something similar to the *server* method in *cfengine copy* where one can provide a server name for the source file. Here is what I have tried and failed :

```
 node 'foo.mydom.org' inherits default {
    include foo_class::setup
 }
```

foo_class::setup defined in the modules/foo_class/setup.pp in the puppet-server node.

```
 class foo_class::setup {
    file {
     "etc_passwd_file" :
       path => "/etc/passwd",
       source => "puppet://bar.mydom.org//${path_to_file}",
    }
  }
```

When running

```
  puppet --noop --server=puppet --no-daemonize --verbose --onetime
```

I get error :

```
 " ..... Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment production source(s) puppet://bar.mydom.org//${path_to_file} at /etc/puppet/modules/foo_class/manifests/setup.pp ...."
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there isn't a way to do this with just Puppet.  Puppet agent processes are able to listen and accept connections, but they don't implement the fileserver like the puppet master does.  The listening behavior of a puppet agent is intended for the `puppet kick` functionality, which is deprecated as of Puppet 3.0 in favor of MCollective.

Comment: thanks. Then I don't understand what the following link is saying. I posted the same question to the google groups, and someone answered. He seems to use virtual resources. I am not understanding his methods clearly yet, but may be he has misunderstood the problem. Your opinion as a developer might be useful. 
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/puppet-users/av6A1BaBegE/sKd6dE6Fq3gJ

Comment: @iamauser I think what that other guy is doing is using storeconfigs to copy the file source from one machine into the storeconfigs database, from where another machine can extract it and write it locally.  It works for some small files (e.g. ssh known host keys) but doesn't scale well and isn't hugely reliable.

Comment: @itsbruce : Thanks. Also I realized that *storeconfigs* are deprecated in latest puppet releases ! Need to find another way to work out this problem...